# Process multiple elements from a big database in Parallel in C#

Tags: c#, parallel-processing

I must migrate a lot of elements from a database (documents stored in a database as byte array) to AWS s3 storage. The algorithm must be something like that:

1. Get the next document (a flag on the table indicates that is not migrated yet)
2. Read the document content
3. Upload to S3
4. Set the S3 guid on the document database and mark as migrated
5. Back to 1 until all documents are migrated

Easy! but I must to run on more than 100 databases with mare than 100k documents while the users are online and I need efficiency but no overload the system, with those premises I designed the following solution:

- Recover 100 elements
- Process in parallel every document (with a MaxDegree to avoid overload)
- Wait until all tasks are finished
- Back to first step until there's no elements

That solution fits my expectations, but I would know if would be a better solution that keeps the "execution flow" at 100%. Perhaps a ProducerConsumer model using TPL and DataFlow but I can't find samples that continuosly gets elements (not repeated) from database.

Comment: How big is each of the document? is it few KB or MB? You could retrieve some 100 unmigrated entries from DB, and insert a tiny message into a Queue, then queue processor can do the job of converting a doc to a S3 object and update the db row with s3 object guid. Data ingestion to queue can check if the total messages in queue is below a threshold , then it can insert the next batch.

Comment: The documents are of various sizes (from few KB to various MB). I like your idea, but would you mark the document in an intermediate state "processing" when it's queued to avoid requeue it?

Comment: Yes, you would need such a flag so that you don't pick up the doc again to enqueue. Also, if your db has some sort of incrementing ID range, you could also keep track in another table - start time, start id, end id, doc_count, to get some visibility on whats going on.